# How to set default app for files for which it wasn't specified? Like a fallback

Tags: windows

How in Windows (in my case 8.1) set the default app that would be set as default for all files that don't have a default app specified?

More specifically, it should act as a fallback app for all files. Meaning, if for a given file the default app is not specified, the fallback is used, otherwise the specified default is used.

**Even more specifically:**

- Specify *Notepad* as the fallback
- There's a file `config`(the default isn't specified)
- There's a file `config.cfg`(the default [for `.cfg`] is *Vim*)
- When opening `config`, *Notepad* is used
- When opening `config.cfg`, *Vim* is used
- If *Vim* ceases to exist(later becomes uninstalled), when opening `config.cfg`, *Notepad* is used

Comment: There is a way by modifying registry values, but could you provide an example like which extension, which program is first and second preference etc.?

Comment: @biswapriyo the OP is saying for all non-specified extensions, i.e., a catch-all.

Answer (score 0):

The best choice might be to add a *right-click context menu entry* for the "wild card" extension, asterisk. *Any* file, when right-clicked, would have an option to open with *Notepad*.

[image: Notepad as wild card choice]

- Open *Regedit* by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>, entering `rege` and selecting *Regedit*.
- Scroll to HKCR\*\shell.
- Right-click on `shell` and select `New > Key`.
- Name the key `Notepad`.
- Right-click on `Notepad` and select `New > Key`.
- Name the key `command`.
- Double-click `Default` and change the text to `notepad.exe "%1"`.

You can also save the following script as a .reg file and merge it. The script also adds the *Notepad* icon to the context menu entry.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Notepad]
"Icon"="Notepad.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Notepad\command]
@="Notepad.exe \"%1\""
```